# Weblogic Server JSESSIONID overwrites between apps under the same domain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, jsessionid

### The problem:

I deployed a ***Spring boot*** application in a ***Weblogic Server*** with other apps running under the same domain. Suppose that I visit my web application and I keep it open in one tab, and then I open a different app of the same domain in a second tab. Then if I switch to my first tab, my endpoints are returning ERROR 500 because the session is null.

I found that the problem is the cookie ***JSESSIONID***, which is overwritten when I open a new app, and then my application backend throws the error.

### The question

So I want to ask, what is the best solution to this problem, without bringing up security issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set a different cookie name for each web app.
To update the cookie used by WebLogic for session afinity change your weblogic.xml file as below :

```
<session-descriptor>
    <cookie-name>[YOUR JSESSIONID NAME]</cookie-name>
    <cookie-domain>[YOUR COOKIE DOMAIN]</cookie-domain>
</session-descriptor>
```

Read this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13711/thin_client.htm#SCPRG138) for details.

Comment: I checked the documentation and there is no mention for cookie-domain. Is the cookie-domain important?

Comment: The tag cookie-domain specifies the domain for which the cookie is valid. It enforces the security. If not set it defaults to the server that issued the cookie.
You can ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The session-descriptor with cookie name (e.g. MYSESSIONID) to the weblogic.xml was the first big step in order to solve the problem. 

The second step was to add 
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=MYSESSIONID
to application properties, in order to be used by Spring Boot.